# Streamlines and line of flow of fluid particles

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

- Can the streamlines of a fluid particle show the position of the particle at a time(using the streamlines)?
- I know that streamlines cannot intersect because at a specific instant the particle reaching the intersection will have two different directions of motion (in the steady flow of particles), but can I say the same thing in turbulent flow for the **line of flow** of the particles, why or why not?
- Is it necessary that a streamline will be a perfect straight line(to a good approximation)? If no why is it called a line then?

Comment: @Fabrice I don't know how or why this happened ?? Never happened before ??,as I only run this site from smartphone??

Comment: Maybe because of the  hash will remove them

Comment: yep ! NB: you get item bullets just using '- blah ' + return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- On a steady flow, streamlines correspond to the trajectory of "fluids particles" or parcels. (Not to be confused with the one of the real "particles" that are the molecules.)
- But if it's not a steady flow, it's wrong. You might even see appearant source and sink in the lines that do not exist as a flow.
- Steady flow streamlines cannot cross because of basic continuity and conservation laws: otherwise a particle should teleport itself on the other side of the obstacle that is the crossing flow ;-)
- A streamline is a curve, not especially a straight line.
- More on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streamlines,_streaklines,_and_pathlines).

Comment: For your first point -- are fluid particles not molecules ?? Then want are they!! Just some imaginary particles!!

Comment: Also can you please clarify the answer of my first question?? Couldn't get it,

Comment: "are fluid particles not molecules ?" : No they aren't. For instance what you think is still air is indeed made of molecules swarming around at very high speed ( ranging up to more than 1000 km/h. And their mutual shock is what makes pressure). Same for what you think is calm water flowing in a precise direction. Fluid "parcels" are the averaging of more complex microscopic motion.

Comment: Also you didn't answer or I couldn't understand!! The  answer to the question that can the LINE OF FLOW (not streamlines) intersect in turbulent flow??

Comment: NB: did you had a look on the definitions and schemes in the wikipedia link I gave ?

Comment: On the case of turbulence, you will have problem at first to define and draw the streamline ! For the velocity field is a kind of fractal up to millimeter to micron scale, good luck to make a curve by joining by continuity the flow tangents (i.e. the local velocities) :-)

Comment: You can't have crossing because you can't have incoherent neighbor velocity directions because matter cannot use teleportation to pass obstacles. 
OR you have to introduce a DIFFERENT notion of streamline, e.g., based only on a blurred approximation of the velocity field (that would wash out the details of turbulence).

Comment: Even though science people don't bother much about the exact definitions ....but still just for the record I think STREAMLINE is a special name of LINE OF FLOW when flow of fluid is STEADY which you have unfortunately accidentally mixed:-)

Answer (score 0):

Two particle cannot overcome each other because if it crosses then the direction of particles will be two different tangents at 1point which is not possible